# Google Rich Snipper structured data - http://schema.org/Recipe - correct way to add ratings

Tags: html, wordpress, schema.org, rich-snippets, structured-data

I have a wordpress site that have posts using "http://schema.org/Recipe"

can someone show me the correct way to add in ratings for "http://schema.org/Recipe"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://schema.org/Rating Copy the code from **JSON-LD** tab in your `header.php`. Use something like this

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Product",
  "aggregateRating": {
    "@type": "AggregateRating",
    "ratingValue": "3.5",
    "reviewCount": "11"
  },
  "description": "0.7 cubic feet countertop microwave. Has six preset cooking categories and convenience features like Add-A-Minute and Child Lock.",
  "name": "Kenmore White 17\" Microwave",
  "offers": {
    "@type": "Offer",
    "availability": "http://schema.org/InStock",
    "price": "55.00",
    "priceCurrency": "USD"
  },
  "review": [
    {
      "@type": "Review",
      "author": "Ellie",
      "datePublished": "2011-04-01",
      "description": "The lamp burned out and now I have to replace it.",
      "name": "Not a happy camper",
      "reviewRating": {
        "@type": "Rating",
        "bestRating": "5",
        "ratingValue": "1",
        "worstRating": "1"
      }
    },
    {
      "@type": "Review",
      "author": "Lucas",
      "datePublished": "2011-03-25",
      "description": "Great microwave for the price. It is small and fits in my apartment.",
      "name": "Value purchase",
      "reviewRating": {
        "@type": "Rating",
        "bestRating": "5",
        "ratingValue": "4",
        "worstRating": "1"
      }
    }
  ]
}
</script>
```

Comment: what if I just add only the HTML/XML Microdata <tags> like "itemprop="aggregateRating", "itemprop="ratingValue" and "itemprop="reviewCount"? and not the "JSON-LD" code into the header.php? will it work?

Comment: is the "<div itemprop="review" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Review">" part necessary? what if I didnt include the "Reviews" will the "rating" and " review count" work without it?

Comment: <div itemprop="review" itemscope itemtype="schema.org/Review"> is very necessary. Otherwise, how will google know that you are using schema review? 

you can use HTML/XML microdata tags too. It's upto you. But I prefer JSON :-)

Comment: I am doing this markup for "recipes" not "products", and if the "reviewcount" is say "3" means , i need to include 3x "<div itemprop="review" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Review">"?

Comment: i had done the "aggregateRating" for some old post a while ago with just only the "itemprop="aggregateRating", "itemprop="ratingValue" and "itemprop="reviewCount" without the "itemprop="review" because the reviews are too long, but google did show the rating + review count in the google search result

Comment: Yes, you need to include itemprop attribute in order to include reviewcount. We use use the itemprop attribute to label properties of an item. It may show review count in google search. But it is useful if you use it. I strongly recommend you to use it

Comment: if the "reviewcount" itemprop is "13" means i need to include exactly 13 "<div itemprop="review" itemscope itemtype="schema.org/Review">" reviews into the structured data?

Comment: no no buddy, 13 is a value. You need to insert the code like this but just once.

<span itemprop="reviewcount">13</span>/
<span itemprop="bestRating">20</span>stars

Comment: in the "JSON-LD", there are a few "@type": "Review"s in the "review": [" array, so if the "reviewcount" = 13, then for the ""@type": "Review" in "review": [", I can just insert 1x review or I need to include 13x?

Comment: I think it's only for one. I'm not entirely  sure.